# I don't fully understand sendSubviewToBack. Please, see the code

Tags: ios, uiview

You can see my screenshot of xib's file.

[image]

I do some manipulation in viewDidLoad

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
 [smallView removeFromSuperview];
 [bigView sendSubviewToBack:smallView];
}
```

Will the hierarchy change from view->bigView->smallView to view->smallView->bigView?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it change the order in the way you state?

Comment: I tried. It changes to view->bigview. I didn't find any smallView. This is strange.

Comment: Well change your question, you know its answer. If you want to know how to do that transformation, or why what you do doesn't work, ask that specifically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No the hierarchy will not be affected. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sendSubviewToBack:) says:

> sendSubviewToBack:
>   Moves the specified subview so that it appears behind its siblings.

It changes the order of painting subviews. If you have two views which are overlapping and have the same superview then you will be able to define which of that two views should be in front.